# SQL join 2 same columns in a result

Tags: sql

So I tried to made s query

```
SELECT FA.code, FA.standing,FA.connection, RE.code, RE.technology 
FROM FA, RE 
WHERE FA.code = RE.code
```

Which created a result

```
code standing connection code technology
XXX   XXX      XXX        XXX    XXX
```

And I need to join the 2 code columns together and join the duplicates as well.

There is very likely an easier way to join these 2 tables without duplicate columns so please I am open to suggestions.

EDIT: for samples I am expecting
`code standing connection technology
XXX    XXX     XXX          XXX`

I want to join the second code column into the first one (both code has mostly the same results so I dont want to show duplicates)

or find completely different way with JOINs

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: @Sukonbu can you provide a sample output which you are expecting?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: @sukonbu See my answer below

Comment: provide table names

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting something like this?

```
SELECT F.code, F.standing, F.connection, R.technology 
FROM FA AS F
INNER JOIN RE AS R ON F.code = R.code
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT FA.code, FA.standing,FA.connection, RE.code, RE.technology 
FROM  table_Name1 FA, table_Name2 RE 
WHERE FA.code = RE.code
```